# Sending a post request in a notification action on Android Wear / Wear OS

Tags: post, action, android-notifications, wear-os

I have a notification in my Wear OS application with an action, and I've been searching how to send a post request when the notification action is triggered. Is there a way to do this?

I know that Android Wear 2.0 has Internet capabilities, and I've seen examples of opening a browser with a notification, but nothing for sending an HTTP request.

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

        Intent respondIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
        PendingIntent respontPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, respondIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action(Resource.Drawable.generic_confirmation,"hello", respontPendingIntent);
        var noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .SetContentTitle("Title").SetContentText("content text")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.pills)
            .AddAction(action);


        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, noti.Build());
```

That's what I have so far (currently the action doesn't do anything).

Comment: Could you clarify what trouble you're having with HTTP? Network access mostly works the same on Wear as on any other Android device; the fact that you're doing it from a notification action doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: the problem is that I haven't found a way to send a request from an intent/action in a notification

Comment: As in I've found no way (so far) to send a request from an intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **many** different ways to accomplish this, but the common theme is that a  `PendingIntent` is just a hook to some other component of your app where the work actually happens. You don't put your HTTP request *in* the `Intent`, as it were, you put it in the app component that the `Intent` invokes.

In your case, rather than opening the `AlarmReceiver` `Activity` from your 'PendingIntent', you'll probably want to launch something like an `IntentService` or a  `BroadcastReceiver` instead and put your network operations in there. If you also need to open `AlarmReceiver`, you can do that in your `BroadcastReceiver` as well.

[Which component to use](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#Components) depends on the bigger picture of what your app is doing, and is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer. But this is pretty basic Android app-architecture stuff, really.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to use a broadcast receiver or an intent service just to send a simple post request, but alas

Comment: If you were doing an HTTP GET, you probably could manage that by encoding the URL into an `Intent`, but not a POST. But even with a GET, there'd be other side effects - like the browser would open to handle the request, and you wouldn't get to also open your `AlarmReceiver`.